# Samba Server needs to have AD authentication

Tags: linux, centos, samba, sssd

My Linux server is connected to AD via Bind DN and password (without domain joining).  It is using sssd for authentication.

I am able to ssh and login without any issue. I have a proper setup of uid and guid, etc. .. There is no issue with logging to the linux server.

I want the samba service to use AD accounts, but I can't find documentation for how to configure it in this case. Can anyone explain how to configure samba to use active directory for authentication on a system using sssd?

Comment: Vivek, welcome to SF, but I fear this question may get closed soon.  We don't take all that well to questions that just say "*please provide me with a configuration file*"; even if they get answered, they're no help to anyone else reading this in the future, as the config file that works for you may not work for them, and they'll be none the wiser.  If the question does get closed, don't take it to heart, but please do read the help documents, especially http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask , before posting again.

Comment: Thanks MadHatter. Non of the forums providing proper detail of configuration in this case So I posted it here. If it gets closed. No issue. Thanks any ways

Comment: Vivek I tried to reword your question to make it more relevant.